# Отправка ajax при checked

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Не получается отправить ajax запрос серверу

```
<div class="test">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="setting">Test
</div>
```

```js
$('.test input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(setting) {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var chkVal = $(this).attr("value");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { val: chkVal },
            beforeSend: function() { alert(chkVal); },
            success: function(data) { alert(data); }
        });
    }
});
```

```php
if($_POST['setting']) {
    $result = add_checked($_POST['setting']);
        if(!$result) {
            exit(FALSE);
        }

    exit(json_encode($result));
}

function add_checked($id_test) {
    $setting = (int)$_POST['setting'];

    $query = "UPDATE test SET setting = '$setting' WHERE id_test = $id_test";
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    return true;
}
```

При клике чекбокса должен отправиться запрос.
В таблицу `test` ячейку `setting` нужно установить `1`

Почему этого не происходит?

Comment: А заходит ли выполнение внутри `if` в javascript? Начинает ли выполняться сам PHP-скрипт? Пишет ли какие-нибудь ошибки консоль браузера (обычно вызывается по нажатию на F12)?

Comment: `$(this).attr("value");` - правильнее использовать `$(this).val();` и `WHERE id_test = $id_test` должно быть `WHERE id_test = '$id_test'`

Comment: если проблема с отправкой формы, то лучше показать html, а не php

Comment: `value` это не статус чекбокса, отправляется всегда единица. На выходе у php ответ возвращается почему-то в виде `json_encode`, когда `add_checked` возвращает всего лишь `(boolean) true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Один checkbox

```
<input id='fuckyeah' type='checkbox' value='1'>
```

```js
checkbox = document.querySelector('#fuckyeah');
checkbox.onchange = function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            settings: 0,
            id: this.value,
            checked: this.checked ? 1:0
        },
        beforeSend: function() { checkbox.disabled = true; },
        complete: function() { checkbox.disabled = false; },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['settings'])) {
    $checkbox = (int) $_POST['id'];
    $checked = (int) $_POST['checked'];

    settingsUpdate($checkbox, $checked);
}

function settingsUpdate($checkbox, $checked) {
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET status = '$checked' WHERE id = $checkbox");
    if(!$query) echo 'err';
}
```

---

#### Несколько checkbox'ов

`value` ид инпута
`name` имя настроек

```
<input class='fuckyeah' type='checkbox' value='1' name='settings'>
<input class='fuckyeah' type='checkbox' value='2' name='settings'>
```

```js
checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.fuckyeah'));
checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox, i) {

    checkbox.onchange = function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                settings: this.name,
                id: this.value,
                checked: this.checked ? 1:0
            },
            beforeSend: function() { checkbox.disabled = true; },
            complete: function() { checkbox.disabled = false; },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['settings'])) {
    $settings = (string) $_POST['settings'];
    $checkbox = (int) $_POST['id'];
    $checked = (int) $_POST['checked'];

    settingsUpdate($settings, $checkbox, $checked);
    echo 'id: '.$checkbox.', status: '.$checked;
}

function settingsUpdate($settings, $checkbox, $checked) {
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE $settings SET status = '$checked' WHERE id = $checkbox");
    if(!$query) echo 'err';
}
```

---

`data_base_name` имя базы данных
`table_name` имя таблицы, в данном случае *settings*

```
    $query = mysql_query("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_base_name`.`table_name` (
            `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
            `checked` INT NOT NULL ,
            PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
        ) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
    ");
```

Comment: При клике на checkbox, в таблицу settings ячейку status где id равен value checkbox'а записывается 0 (не стоит галочка) или 1 (стоит галочка). Также при запросе нужно блокировать checkbox, пока не придёт ответ или не выйдет время запроса

Comment: я конечно извиняюсь но ничего не получается у меня таблица выглядит вот так 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (
  `id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `checked` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
если сможете помогите пож.

Comment: @Seva, добавил пример создания таблицы

Comment: При отправке выдает вот такой результат, я не знаю это правильно или нет http://prntscr.com/bftk5f

Comment: @Seva, ответ не должен быть json

Comment: @Seva, если есть vk, могу помочь

Comment: Спасибо заранее http://vk.com/sevasargsyan